# Complete list of possible database "objects"?

Tags: database-theory

When I finished my degree in Programming and Database I remember there being a general list of database "objects" like this:

- data types (a list unto itself)
- fields
- records
- tables
- views (sort of like stored queries you can re-run)
- relations between tables (foreign keys)
- transactions (not really an object but something in the database)
- connections
- users
- groups
- permissions
- triggers
- stored procs

Have there been any additions to this list since then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the information_schema objects from **MySQL**, if that helps:

```
CHARACTER_SETS
COLLATIONS
COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY
COLUMNS
COLUMN_PRIVILEGES
ENGINES
EVENTS
FILES
GLOBAL_STATUS
GLOBAL_VARIABLES
INNODB_CMP
INNODB_CMPMEM
INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET
INNODB_CMP_RESET
INNODB_LOCKS
INNODB_LOCK_WAITS
INNODB_TRX
KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
PARAMETERS
PARTITIONS
PLUGINS
PROCESSLIST
PROFILING
REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS
ROUTINES
SCHEMATA
SCHEMA_PRIVILEGES
SESSION_STATUS
SESSION_VARIABLES
STATISTICS
TABLES
TABLESPACES
```

Don't forget indexes, and materilized views.

Here are the catalog objects for **Postgres**:

```
administrable_role_authorizations   
applicable_roles    
attributes  
check_constraint_routine_usage  
check_constraints   
column_domain_usage 
column_privileges   
column_udt_usage    
columns 
constraint_column_usage 
constraint_table_usage  
data_type_privileges    
domain_constraints  
domain_udt_usage    
domains 
element_types   
enabled_roles   
information_schema_catalog_name 
key_column_usage    
parameters  
referential_constraints 
role_column_grants  
role_routine_grants 
role_table_grants   
role_usage_grants   
routine_privileges  
routines    
schemata    
sequences   
sql_features    
sql_implementation_info 
sql_languages   
sql_packages    
sql_parts   
sql_sizing  
sql_sizing_profiles 
table_constraints   
table_privileges    
tables  
triggered_update_columns    
triggers    
usage_privileges    
view_column_usage   
view_routine_usage  
view_table_usage    
views
```

Answer (score 4):

Some more:

- domains
- synonyms
- sequences
- rules
- constraints
- assertions (though I don't know of any DBMS supporting them)
- indexes
- roles
- user defined (object) types

Answer (score 2):

Objects in Oracle:

```
CLUSTER
CONSUMER GROUP
CONTEXT
DATABASE LINK
DESTINATION
DIRECTORY
EDITION
EVALUATION CONTEXT
FUNCTION
INDEX
INDEX PARTITION
INDEXTYPE
JAVA CLASS
JAVA DATA
JAVA RESOURCE
JAVA SOURCE
JOB
JOB CLASS
LIBRARY
LOB
LOB PARTITION
MATERIALIZED VIEW
OPERATOR
PACKAGE
PACKAGE BODY
PROCEDURE
PROGRAM
QUEUE
RESOURCE PLAN
RULE
RULE SET
SCHEDULE
SCHEDULER GROUP
SEQUENCE
SYNONYM
TABLE
TABLE PARTITION
TABLE SUBPARTITION
TRIGGER
TYPE
TYPE BODY
UNDEFINED
VIEW
WINDOW
XML SCHEMA
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically in relational databases, we have columns and rows, not fields and records.

In relational database theory, the term relation is used to refer to a table.  Rows in a table are equivalent to tuples of attributes (equivalent to columns) which are "related" to various candidate keys, one of which is identified as the primary key.